# Trivial representation, sign representation of $gl_n$.

Tags: representation-theory, quantum-groups

How to write down the action of trivial representation and sign representation of $U_q(gl_n)$?

The algebra $U_q(gl_n)$ is generated by $E_i, F_i, K_i$, $i=1,2,\ldots, n-1$.

Let $\mathbb{C} \cong \mathbb{C}v$ be the trivial representation of $U_q(gl_n)$. Then $x.v=v$ for all $x \in U_q(gl_n)$.

What is the formula for the $U_q(gl_n)$-action in the case when $V$ is the sign representation?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I would say $x \cdot v = e(x)v$ where $e(x) = 1$ if $x$ has positive determinant, and $e(x) = -1$ else.

Comment: Just a clarification: Should you not also have the inverses of the $K$s?